# Unable to open Arduino device

Tags: arduino

I have a problem opening an Arduino device: I tried everything, but it keeps giving me this error message. Does anybody know how to fix it?

I use Wolfram Mathematica 13.0 on Windows 10. I downloaded Arduino IDE and it runs perfectly on its own, and I can upload code to the Arduino with it. But it is impossible to do the same with Wolfram.

```
DeviceOpen["Arduino", "COM5"]
```

[image: error: checking the size of the sketch with avr-size failed with code 1 ...]

Comment: Have you seen [Basic Arduino / Mathematica Connection](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/237006/27951)? Or this [device connection guide for Arduino](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/device/Arduino.html)? Have you tried a different serial port, just to make sure?

Comment: Hello.. This look more a problem with the C++ compiler.  Check on this  to update. Get System Information ->kernel->External Compilers.  Read back what are the external C compilers available.   Update your Arduino IDE.